# Scala Test "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" after sbt clean compile with JDK7

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, unsupported-class-version

There must be hundreds of this type of error on Stackoverflow, but none of them apply to me. I know exactly what this error means but here my facts:

1. It is a multi-module Scala lift project
2. I use sdk man and it is set to JDK 7u141-zulu and Scala 2.11.8
3. Intellij Project (and all modules) are pointed to same JDK
4. Other tests run in IDE fine
5. sbt test runs fine in terminal
6. I have deleted every target dir "find . -name target -type d -exec rm -rf {} \; " and rebuilt the project in IntelliJ
7. I have deleted my ~/.ivy2/cache dir and redownloaded everything while JAVA_HOME=jdk7
8. Searched the path in code below for "java/8.*". There are 138 occurance of "java/7" but zero of "java/8".
9. Prayed to the old gods and the new
10. Thrown chairs and flipped tables

I do not know why i'm getting this error when I run this test. How and where could it have compiled with Java 8 (version 52).

Any source of sanity would be welcomed right now.

```
Testing started at 18:06 ...
/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=60556:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/p2730851/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.3/Scala/lib/runners.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/lib/dt.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/lib/jconsole.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/lib/tools.jar:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/out/test/client:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/out/production/client:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/client/billing/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/client/billing/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/cache/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/cache/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/model/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/model/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/parsing/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/parsing/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/utility/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/utility/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/fictus/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/fictus/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/scuttle/scuttle/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/scuttle/scuttle/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/shiny-toolbox/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/shiny-toolbox/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/test-model/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/http/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/http/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/caching/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/caching/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/circuit-breaker/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/common/circuit-breaker/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/haven/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/haven/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/jsr166e-java6/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/twc_oss/jsr166e-java6/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/client/database/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/client/database/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/identity/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/identity/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/scuttle/scuttle-twitter-convert/target/test-classes:/Users/p2730851/Projects/cst/cst/core/scuttle/scuttle-twitter-convert/target/classes:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/asm/asm/jars/asm-3.3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/jars/bcmail-jdk14-136.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/jars/bcprov-jdk14-136.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/cglib/cglib/jars/cglib-2.2.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/bundles/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.2.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.googlecode.xmemcached/xmemcached/jars/xmemcached-1.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/jars/hazelcast-3.6.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-client/jars/hazelcast-client-3.6.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.mchange/c3p0/jars/c3p0-0.9.5-pre5.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.mchange/mchange-commons-java/jars/mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.oracle/ojdbc14/jars/ojdbc14-1.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.6.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc/epgs-dto-scala_2.10/jars/epgs-dto-scala_2.10-0.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc/sbt-junit/jars/sbt-junit-0.3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc.atgw.naturalsearch/twc-naturalsearch-dsquery/jars/twc-naturalsearch-dsquery-2.7.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc.atgw.naturalsearch/twc-naturalsearch-search-api/jars/twc-naturalsearch-search-api-2.7.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc.atgw.naturalsearch/twc-naturalsearch-search-impl-ds/jars/twc-naturalsearch-search-impl-ds-2.7.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc.cst/config/jars/config-3.7.12.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twc.cst.adobe/verifier/jars/verifier-1.1.1511.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twcable.delphi-soap/soap/jars/soap-2.4.48.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-core_2.10/jars/finagle-core_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-http_2.10/jars/finagle-http_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-kestrel_2.10/jars/finagle-kestrel_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-memcached_2.10/jars/finagle-memcached_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-serversets_2.10/jars/finagle-serversets_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-stream_2.10/jars/finagle-stream_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-test_2.10/jars/finagle-test_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/finagle-thrift_2.10/jars/finagle-thrift_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/scrooge-core_2.10/jars/scrooge-core_2.10-3.16.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-app_2.10/jars/util-app_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-codec_2.10/jars/util-codec_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-collection_2.10/jars/util-collection_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-core_2.10/jars/util-core_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-hashing_2.10/jars/util-hashing_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-jvm_2.10/jars/util-jvm_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-logging_2.10/jars/util-logging_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-zk-common_2.10/jars/util-zk-common_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/util-zk_2.10/jars/util-zk_2.10-6.22.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/application-action/jars/application-action-0.0.75.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/args/jars/args-0.2.13.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/args-apt/jars/args-apt-0.1.17.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/args-core/jars/args-core-0.1.18.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/base/jars/base-0.0.95.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/collections/jars/collections-0.0.82.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/dynamic-host-set/jars/dynamic-host-set-0.0.47.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/io/jars/io-0.0.56.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/io-json/jars/io-json-0.0.44.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/io-thrift/jars/io-thrift-0.0.53.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/jdk-logging/jars/jdk-logging-0.0.54.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/net-util/jars/net-util-0.0.84.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/quantity/jars/quantity-0.0.79.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/service-thrift/jars/service-thrift-1.0.51.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/stat/jars/stat-0.0.39.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/stat-registry/jars/stat-registry-0.0.35.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/stats/jars/stats-0.0.98.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/stats-provider/jars/stats-provider-0.0.66.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/util/jars/util-0.0.106.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/util-executor-service-shutdown/jars/util-executor-service-shutdown-0.0.55.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/util-sampler/jars/util-sampler-0.0.61.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common/util-system-mocks/jars/util-system-mocks-0.0.81.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common.zookeeper/client/jars/client-0.0.60.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common.zookeeper/group/jars/group-0.0.78.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.common.zookeeper/server-set/jars/server-set-1.0.83.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/javax.inject/javax.inject/jars/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/javax.mail/mail/jars/mail-1.4.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit-dep/jars/junit-dep-4.10.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/net.liftweb/lift-common_2.10/jars/lift-common_2.10-2.5.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/net.liftweb/lift-json-ext_2.10/jars/lift-json-ext_2.10-2.5.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/net.liftweb/lift-json_2.10/jars/lift-json_2.10-2.5.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-api/jars/cxf-api-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-common-utilities/jars/cxf-common-utilities-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/jars/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/jars/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-core/jars/cxf-rt-core-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/jars/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/jars/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/jars/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-common/jars/cxf-rt-transports-common-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/jars/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/jars/cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.cxf/cxf-tools-common/jars/cxf-tools-common-2.4.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.neethi/neethi/bundles/neethi-3.0.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.thrift/libthrift/jars/libthrift-0.5.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ws.xmlschema/xmlschema-core/bundles/xmlschema-core-2.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/jars/zookeeper-3.3.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/jars/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.clapper/grizzled-slf4j_2.10/jars/grizzled-slf4j_2.10-1.0.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/jars/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.10.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/jars/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/jars/woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.easymock/easymock/jars/easymock-3.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.fontbox/fontbox/jars/fontbox-0.1.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/jars/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/jars/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/jars/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.jempbox/jempbox/jars/jempbox-0.2.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-1.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.mockito/mockito-core/jars/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.objenesis/objenesis/jars/objenesis-1.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.objenesis/objenesis/jars/objenesis-2.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.10.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/test-interface/jars/test-interface-1.0.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10/bundles/scalatest_2.10-2.2.4.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/jars/slf4j-nop-1.7.12.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/jars/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-asm/jars/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-web/jars/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/org.squeryl/squeryl_2.10/jars/squeryl_2.10-0.9.5-6.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/pdfbox/pdfbox/jars/pdfbox-0.7.3.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/postgresql/postgresql/jars/postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc3.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/jars/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar:/Users/p2730851/.ivy2/cache/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/jars/xml-resolver-1.2.jar" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s com.twc.cst.client.device.DeviceManagementClientTest -testName "areDevicesTr69Managed should parse and return two results" -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter -showProgressMessages true
objc[34938]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/bin/java (0x10f1274b0) and /Users/p2730851/.sdkman/candidates/java/7.0.141-zulu/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10f1ab4c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/testingSupport/scalaTest/ScalaTestRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Where is Intellij getting this version 52.0? is there somewhere I haven't looked? and why only this Test?

Comment: More Info: Intellij Version 2017.3

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Comment: In IntelliJ -> Project structure -> Project Settings -> Project (and Modules -> Sources) , what is the configured language level (3rd input from top)?

Comment: You said that the target Scala version is 2.11.8. However, there are lots of dependencies on the classpath that are using Scala 2.10.*, even `scalatest_2.10-2.2.4.jar`. Have you tried to adjust them?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but PDFBox 0.7.3 ? That one is 12 years old.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know why i'm getting this error when I run this test. How and where could it have compiled with Java 8 (version 52).

The error tells you exactly which class is the problem: `org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner`. It isn't in your project, it's part of IDEA. So it was compiled when IDEA was built and your project's compilation settings can't affect it.

Though given this, I don't understand why "Other tests run in IDE fine".

Similarly, I don't believe "redownloading everything while JAVA_HOME=jdk7" can help; the downloaded jars will be the same and require whatever version of Java they were compiled to require.

Instead you'll need to investigate every dependency separately (and their transitive dependencies), and possibly download their sources, try to recompile them with Java 7 (modifying if necessary) and publish locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still helps. I switched the JRE in "Edit Configurations" to 1.8 (apparently IntelliJ uses JRE 1.8 and ScalaTestRunner is also compiled with that) and the tests ran successfully.

[image]